# liferay 6.2GA2 soap authentication with python suds client

Tags: python, authentication, soap, liferay, suds

I've got some problems with the liferay 6.2 soap api: i need it to search users with the python suds client.

In liferay 6.1, i used the following code, it worked well:

```
from suds.client import Client
c = Client('http://liferay62instance.domain.com/api/secure/axis/Portal_UserService?wsdl', username='liferayuser', password='liferaypassword')
c.service.getUserByScreenName(companyId=10154, screenName='user')
```

In liferay 6.2, the wsdl url has changed and doesn't require an http authentication by default, so using the following code gives an error:

```
from suds.client import Client
c = Client('http://liferay62instance.domain.com/api/axis/Portal_UserService?wsdl', username='liferayuser', password='liferaypassword')
c.service.getUserByScreenName(companyId=10154, screenName='user')
```

and the error:

```
Server raised fault: 'java.rmi.RemoteException: Authenticated access required'
```

with the server side traceback:

```
14:50:45,030 ERROR [ajp-bio-9009-exec-8][UserServiceSoap:845]
java.lang.SecurityException: Authenticated access required
java.lang.SecurityException: Authenticated access required
```

Do you have any idea on how to pass soap authentication in liferay 6.2??

Thanks for any answser.

Jérôme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i managed my issue using **HttpAuthenticated** transport **from suds.transport.http**

Using it adds a new header **Authorization** with a base64 encoded combinaison of username + password and will be used in each soap request.

Here's an example:

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.transport.http import HttpAuthenticated

t = HttpAuthenticated(username='liferayuser', password='liferaypassword')
c = Client('http://liferay62instance.domain.com/api/axis/Portal_UserService?wsdl', transport=t)
result = c.service.getUserByScreenName(companyId=10154, screenName='user')
```